# PHP/(bad) exif data/warnings, what to do?

Tags: php, exif

I'm writing a small script that gathers a couple exif values from images... namely the creation date, make and model.

I'm noticing (particularly with image mailed through the default iPhone mail app) that the exif data has been altered, which is a known issue (the mail app compresses images before sending them, even when 'full size' is selected). The values I'm looking for appear to be there, although I get PHP warnings accessing them. No problems actually getting the values, but the warning obviously isn't working for me.

Calling ini_set('display_errors',0) hides the warnings, but seems sloppy to me. Is there any way I can ignore this warning, on this script, for this scenario that is a little better?

My initial thought was wrapping everything in a try/catch, but the warning is still displayed prominently on the page.

I'm simply using the standard exif_read_data() function, I think an external library would be a little much for what little I need.

PHP:

```
if($_GET['i']) {
  $input = strtolower($_GET['i'] . ".jpg");
  if(file_exists($input)) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($input);
    foreach($exif as $key => $value) {
      if(!in_array($key, Array("DateTime","Make","Model"))) {
        unset($exif[$key]);
      }
    }
    ksort($exif);
    print_r($exif);
  }
}
```

Warning:

`Warning: exif_read_data(trailmarker.jpg) [exif_read_data]: Illegal IFD size: x00C4 + 2 + x3239*12 = x25B70 > x2B74 in C:\xampp\htdocs\exif\dumpfolder\exif.php on line 5`

Comment: Can you show the exact code you are using, and the exact warnings you are getting?

Comment: `<?php
$input = "someimage.jpg";

$result = exif_read_data($input);

foreach($result as $key => $value) {
  if(!in_array($key, Array("DateTime","Make","Model"))) {
    unset($result[$key]);
  }
}
?>`

Comment: ah, well I don't know how to use StackOverflow obviously... :(

Comment: Is this a joke? I really hope so... Warnings must be there for a reason, I think. Even though, of course, sometimes @ is handy to suppress warning and throw an exception instead. But that's a different beast from considering everything cool. Just my 2 cc.

Comment: @maraspin it's been a while, so lemme try to remember exactly what the problem was... exif data is notoriously "dirty" (meaning it's corrupt/missing/has any number of issues). I needed a quick way to suppress outputing an error to the user when a known wacky input was coming in. The accepted answer was a fairly quick easy solution that fit the bill nicely at the time. I just didn't know you could suppress function errors at the time they're called. Simple. In hindsight, this case could probably use a try/catch and be a little more "correct".

Comment: You're totally right about exif being dirty stuff, jeff. And I totally understand your point. Actually, my comment was only directed toward @jnpcl statement saying that real programmers don't care about warnigs. Or maybe real ones don't ...but I'm sure good ones do. ;-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the [@ operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to hide the warning without using display_errors, i.e.

```
$exif = @exif_read_data(..);
```

That's better than setting [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) because it silences warnings/errors on the exif read function only, and does not hide other possible errors in your code.

Comment: Always a bad idea to use the @ operator. If something is broken, you should deal with it.

Comment: This is the last resort.

Answer (score 6):

Despite this is on old topic, it came for me out of nowhere with new php 7.2:
[Bug #75785 Many errors from exif_read_data](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75785)

I agree with @maraspin, as any error is for a reason and not dealing with it means having poor performance (time, features).

**MY GOAL**: to get 'DateTimeOriginal' of uploadable image (and not just creation_date of tmp file - DateTime).

**1. Normal using of exif_read_data:**

```
$exif = exif_read_data(tmp/phpTBAlvX); or
$exif = exif_read_data($file->tempName, 'ANY_TAG'); or
$exif = exif_read_data($file->tempName, 'IFD0'); or
$exif = exif_read_data($file->tempName, 'EXIF');
```

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException exif_read_data(tmp/phpTBAlvX):
>   Process tag(x010D=DocumentNam): Illegal components(0)

**2. Using the [@ operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to hide the warning:**

```
$exif = @exif_read_data(tmp/phpTBAlvX);
```

> RESULT: $exif as array with 20 arguments, but no 'DateTimeOriginal' in it

```
    Array (
    [FileName] => phphT9mZy
    [FileDateTime] => 1529171254
    ...
    [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, EXIF
    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="3968" height="2976"
            [Height] => 2976
            [Width] => 3968
            ...
        )
    [ImageWidth] => 3968
    [ImageLength] => 2976
    [BitsPerSample] => Array()
    [ImageDescription] => cof
    [Make] => HUAWEI
    ...
    [DateTime] => 2018:06:14 12:00:38
    [YCbCrPositioning] => 1
)
```

**3. Ended with solution:**

```
$img = new \Imagick(tmp/phpTBAlvX);
$allProp = $img->getImageProperties();
$exifProp = $img->getImageProperties("exif:*");
```

> RESULT: $allProp as array with 70 arguments with 'DateTimeOriginal'

```
Array (
    [date:create] => 2018-06-16T21:15:24+03:00
    [date:modify] => 2018-06-16T21:15:24+03:00
    [exif:ApertureValue] => 227/100
    [exif:BitsPerSample] => 8, 8, 8
    ...
    [exif:DateTimeOriginal] => 2018:06:14 12:00:38
    [jpeg:colorspace] => 2
    [jpeg:sampling-factor] => 2x2,1x1,1x1
)
```

> RESULT: $exifProp as array with 66 arguments with 'DateTimeOriginal'

```
Array (
    [exif:ApertureValue] => 227/100
    [exif:BitsPerSample] => 8, 8, 8
    ...
    [exif:DateTimeOriginal] => 2018:06:14 12:00:38
)
```

**MY DECISION:**

1. never use @ for suppressing any warning or code
2. use [The Imagick class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) for getting any tag of an image

Comment: Thanks for posting this and for linking the relevant issue! I can still confirm this on PHP 7.2.11 x64 on Windows. Furthermore, I fully agree that the decision you took at the time was the correct one, as it’s obviously still broken. But it’s not good advice *in general*, as it’s better to use PHP’s built-in method again as soon as it’s fixed, rather than relying on yet another external dependency, i.e. ImageMagick, which has a long history of frequent and serious security vulnerabilities by the way.

Comment: im now wondering if this is just a windows issue and im sitting here debugging a issue on local that isnt even on the server