# Google App Engine PHP exif_read_data function

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I need to rotate image according to image orientation and resize it.
i get the image orientation from exif_read_data($source) function.

in dev server when i do.

```
$source="https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/file.jpg"
$data=exif_read_data(($source));
```

it works.

but at production server. it doesn't.

it gives me this error

```
exif_read_data(file.jpg): Error reading from file: got=x3FFA(=16378) != itemlen-2=x49DE(=18910)
```

and after changing $source to absolute path

```
$source="gs://bucket/file.jpg"
$data=exif_read_data(($source));
```

it return this error in both developement and production.

```
exif_read_data(file.jpg): File too small (0)
```

How do i get it works in production server?

Comment: Have you tried a different file?

Comment: @Mars sorry, i can just reply now. i have try to change the file, but it give same error.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of different php versions on dev and prod servers. For example as it comes from that bug report: [Bug #75785    Many errors from exif_read_data](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75785)

The solution might be to use

```
$img = new \Imagick(file.jpg);
$allProp = $img->getImageProperties();
$exifProp = $img->getImageProperties("exif:*");
```

The full story for that solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184748/php-bad-exif-data-warnings-what-to-do/50890651#50890651)