# exif_read_data() returning false even though there is metadata present in jpeg

Tags: php, exif

For some reason exif_read_data() returns false on every image in the directory even though I know that all my jpeg images have metadata properties.

I am by no means a PHP wizard yet so perhaps I have a syntax error or I'm just missing something fairly obvious to those of you who are PHP wizards.

```
galleryData.metadata = <?php
    $dir_path = "Assets/Images/portfolio/";
    if (is_dir($dir_path)) {
        $files = scandir($dir_path);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
            $tempPath = $dir_path + $files[$i];
            $metadata[$i] = exif_read_data($tempPath);
        }
        echo json_encode($metadata);
    }
?>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully figured it out I wasn't combining my strings properly. Below is my fixed and working code.

```
galleryData.metadata = <?php
    $metadata = array();
    if (is_dir($dir_path)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
            $metadata[$i] = exif_read_data("{$dir_path}{$files[$i]}", null, true);
        }
        echo json_encode($metadata);
    }
?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

might be a solution, but need to have more info real error (error message ?)

exif_read_data() can be buggy prom php version to version: 
[Bug #75785 Many errors from exif_read_data](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75785)

The solution might be to use

```
$img = new \Imagick(DSC01386.jpg);
$allProp = $img->getImageProperties();
$exifProp = $img->getImageProperties("exif:*");
```

[The Imagick class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php), is quite powerful class (rotations etc).

The full story for that solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184748/php-bad-exif-data-warnings-what-to-do/50890651#50890651)

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a better solution then what I was using (PHP noob) although I did get it working I was just adding strings wrong in PHP lol